# Assign Base Class Property Values to Derived Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having a base model and a view model derived from it.

**Base Model**

```
public class Feed
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

**Derived Model**

```
public class FeedViewModel :  Feed
{
   public bool EditMode { get; set; }    
}
```

**Data Access Layer**

```
public Feed GetFeed(){
   --db code to retreive all feed
}
```

**Controller**

```
public FeedController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
        var data = DAL.GetFeed();
        var model = new FeedViewModel{ EditMode = true };

         model.Id = data.Id;
         model.Name = data.Name;
         model.Url = data.Url;   //This is working

       //But i dont want like this, coz i cant reassign all the proerties again. Is there any other easy way like this
        model = (FeedViewModel)data;
    } 
 }
```

I dont want to reassign all the properties values again to derived model. Instead i am looking for any other easy way? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using composition instead of inheritance:

```
public class FeedViewModel
{
    public bool EditMode { get; set; }    
    public Feed Feed { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
var data = DAL.GetFeed();
var model = new FeedViewModel { EditMode = true, Feed = data };
```

Fundamentally I wouldn't expect a view-model to be the same as the model it's a view-model for - I'd want to be able to *use* that model, but I wouldn't expect to use inheritance for it.

The view model can expose properties of the view via delegation, should you wish - possibly with property change notification.

EDIT: Another alternative (which may not be applicable either - we have no idea how much you *can* change in this project) is to make your `GetFeed` method generic in the DAL:

```
public Feed GetFeed<T>() where T : Feed, new()
{
   --db code to retreive all feed
}
```

Then you can call it with:

```
var model = DAL.GetFeed<FeedViewModel>();
model.EditMode = true;
```

Comment: @Thanks, +1 for good suggesstion. But sorry i would like to extend the base model with some more properties in view model, and so i cant use composition. Any other ideas?

Comment: @SSS: That just says "I can't use composition because I want to use inheritance" - it doesn't give any reason *why* you want to use inheritance. Again, I would strongly advise *against* inheritance here. I wouldn't expect code to want to treat a view model as the original model, so why do you want to use inheritance?

Comment: @Yeah i understood, but i am currently in maintenance project and there implemented `FeedViewModel` is a derived object from `Feed` and if i change to composition there involves a lot of refactoring work. And so i am need of what i asked. Hope you understand

Comment: @SSS: Well if you can't do things the *nice* way, you'll have to do them the *ugly* way which you've already seen - copying the properties from one object to another. That sort of ugliness is what tends to happen in a badly-designed object model.

Comment: @SSS Have you looked into [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)? As long as the properties are named the same, which they will be since you're using inheritance, it will do the copying for you.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Thanks for the better answer... But that doesn't meets my need sorry...

Comment: @SSS: The ultimate answer is that there *isn't* anything to meet your apparent desire to change the type of an existing object. Either you'll need to change `GetFeed` so it can return a `FeedViewModel`, or you'll need to copy the properties from one object to another *somewhere*. That could be in the `FeedViewModel` constructor, it could be using AutoMapper... various options. But you're simply not going to be able to change the type of the existing object.

Comment: @SSS: See my edit for more details of the "change GetFeed" approach. But we're really in the dark about what kind of answer you're looking for here.

Answer (score 0):

Using [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper).

Create an `AutoMapperConfig` class like so:

```
public class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static void CreateMaps()
    {
        // Feed domain / view model mappings
        Mapper.CreateMap<FeedViewModel, Feed>()
        Mapper.CreateMap<Feed, FeedViewModel>();            
    }
}
```

Call your `CreateMaps()` method from your `Global.asax` to register the mappings at application start.

Now in your `Action` all you need to do is this:

```
public FeedController : Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
        var data = DAL.GetFeed();
        var model = Mapper.Map<Feed, FeedViewModel>(data);
        model.EditMode = true;

        return View(model)
    } 
 }
```

And then in some other action you just reverse the process

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeOtherAction()
{
    FeedViewModel model = new FeedViewModel();
    TryUpdateModel(model);

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var feed = Mapper.Map<FeedViewModel, Feed>(model);
        DAL.UpdateFeed(feed);
    }

    return View(model)
}
```